# Apache2 running slow with site on VirtualBox Share

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-http-server

I`m running an Ubuntu 16.04 guest on a Ubuntu 14.04 host in VirtualBox.

On the host, I have an Wordpress installation in the folder `/home/myuser/wordpress`. I add this folder to the "Shared Folder" list in the guest machine VirtualBox settings.

Then I configured the apache on the guest machine, so that he loads the website from this shared folder. Everythings works, but it is very slow (10 seconds for a Wordpress backend load).

When I copy `/home/myuser/wordpress` to the guest machines virtual drive, e.g. in /var/www/wordpress on the guest, and point apache to that folder, it runs in 2 seconds.

Why is the virtual box share so slow? And are there possibilitys to increase the performance? Or are there another possibilities to share files between host and guest?

Comment: What do you mean by `Virtual box share` and by `linked a virtual server`, and were all your tests done from a different host?

Comment: With virtual box share, I mean the "Shared Folder" option. The Wordpress installation is on my host machine, and in the virtualbox preferences of the guest machine, it is added with option "Auto-Mount"

Comment: With `linked a virtual server` I just mean, apaches virtual host config (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apache/Virtual_Hosts/). I`ll edit this in my question.

Comment: What you need to clarify is the difference between both scenarios which is quite unclear.

Comment: You are right, bad description. Edited it, I think it`s more clear now.

Comment: Make sure you've installed the latest guest addons first.  If that doesn't solve it, try changing the VM's network adapter to `Intel Pro 1000MT`.

Comment: Latest guest additions are installed, Adapter is at Intel Pro 1000MT Desktop(82540EM). How could the network adapter slow down the share?

Comment: It's a VM after all and that could add issues, but apparently that's not your problem.  If I were you, I'd simply create a samba share and use that instead of the VirtualBox share, or direct the web traffic to the VM as would be expected in that kind of setup.  Not sure why you'd create a VM to simply share its disk space.

Comment: Samba is a tool for a windows share, right?

Comment: Yes, but it has become widely used for Unix shares too because of the multiple issues with classic NFS implementations.